# Break out of looper in thread

Tags: android

I have a service class that includes a thread sub-class which includes a Looper and its used to carry out some calculations while the app is running. My question is, how do I break out of the looper in order for the thread to terminate along with the service? The `.interrupt()` doesn't seem to be working because the thread still shows up in the logs after the app is paused.

```
 public class serviceClass extends Service{
    Thread innerThread = new InnerThread();
    onCreate{
        innerThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
           innerThread.interrupt();
        }

    private class InnerThread implements Runnable{

        Looper.prepare
        doStuff()
        //.
        //.
        Looper.Loop
        //other stuff to do before exiting the thread()
        }
 }
```

Comment: Just to be clear `after the app is paused.` do you mean after app is killed or after app is put in background?

Comment: @Sagar Both. In the main activity both `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` methods stop the service.

Comment: @John.E have you try `Looper.myLooper().quit();`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://file:///C:/Users/sbegale/Desktop/tools/android_sdk/sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows-kitkat-seek/docs/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) calling `threadObj.interrupt()` has following impact:

> Posts an interrupt request to this Thread. The behavior depends on the state of this Thread:
>
> - Threads blocked in one of Object's wait() methods or one of Thread's join() or sleep() methods will be woken up, their interrupt
>     status will be cleared, and they receive an InterruptedException.
> - Threads blocked in an I/O operation of an InterruptibleChannel will have their interrupt status set and receive an
>     ClosedByInterruptException. Also, the channel will be closed.
> - Threads blocked in a Selector will have their interrupt status set and return immediately. They don't receive an exception in this case.

If your thread is not in any of the state above, then this method will only set the interrupt status to `true`. If you want your thread to exit, you have to explicitly check the `isInterrupted()`flag as follows:

```
 private class InnerThread implements Runnable{
     @Override
     public void run() {
         if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
             //do action
         }
     }
 }
```